help needed setting up tor2web proxy
I want to setup a tor2web proxy which will allow me to access onion sites with regular browsers[ like in the case with onionsitehere.onion.ly ]
But I want to set it up locally.
Is it possible to access onion sites in regular browser with a tor2web proxy locally?
http://localhost/onionsitehere.onion like this?
if yes, how to set it up?
Thank you!

sure! And you don't even need the tor2web package: just use your Tor instance's SOCKS proxy endpoint for DNS and SOCKS - and any browser that is capable of using SOCKS proxy will be working in the way you want. And - yes - you're absolutely correct about local setup, do not use any public services for thing like this
